# Boosting ajax performance by faking the server response

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm wondering what some of you Ajax/jQuery gurus think about the approach of updating the page when an Ajax call starts, without waiting for the server to return the response.

For example, imagine you're developing a page like GMail. When the user deletes an email, you should remove that DIV, LI, whatever HTML element represents it from the DOM. One way to do this is to make an Ajax call to the server, wait for the server to actually delete the data in the database, and then it can return a JSON including the ID of the email to delete in DOM. Then, we can remove this element from DOM in "success" method of Ajax request.

While this to me is the most logical and clean way of doing this, sometimes processing on the server may take a little while. In such cases, we can remove the element from DOM BEFORE even hitting the server. To the user, this looks like a significant boost in the performance of application.

Whilst the second approach may be useful in scenarios where performance is more important than efficiency, it may be undesirable in other cases where the expected response is more than just deleting something on the client. An example could be adding some sort of hierarchical/nested elements with CSS classes. Generating these content on the server is easier (as I'm assuming it should already be available there as some sort of PartialView in ASP.NET MVC or equivalent in other technologies). Building these markups on the client can get a bit tricky and may end up in a mess. I'm aware there are methods like jQuery tmpl() out there that facilitate this. But we are in fact duplicating the layout of a given response: One version on the server and one on the client. Things can get out of sync and also get harder to test.

Just wondering if anyone has come across scenarios like this. Please share your thoughts and experiences.

Cheers,
Mosh

Comment: This is a great observation. Unfortunately SO isn't for thoughts and experiences, it's for problem-solving; answering questions which have an expected outcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the div right away before getting a response back I think that is fine only if you specify an error function to be called which would redisplay the div with some type of error message.

It would be a bad idea to hide the div, have the server return an error, and then never inform the user that the item was deleted.

Whether you want to remove the element or hide it is up to you, but either way I would implement a way for you to redisplay it if the operation failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a desirable way to implement user interfacing operations as long as your error handling is robust and you can put the state back to the correct state if the server is unreachable or returns an error.  There is absolutely no need to make the user wait for an operation that almost always succeeds as long as you can properly handle the rare case when the operation fails.

`Optimize the experience for the 99% case, handle the 1% case intelligently if it happens.`